# Drag Drop - From table to UL / LI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

at the moment I am stuck. I would like to drag/drop a table row to a li element.

The content or dom element should not move "automatically" there. I only need an event where I can get the element that is moved and the target, where it was dropped.

I created a fiddle based on another questions fiddle. I hope someone can assist.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(function($) {
   $('#list2 tr.document').draggable({
     cursor: 'move',
     helper: 'clone',
     connectToSortable: "#list1",
   });
   $('#list1').sortable({
     revert: true,
   });
 });
</script>

folders
<ul id='list1'>
  <li class="folderentry">Some
    <ul>
      <li class="folderentry">2nd level</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Thing</li>
</ul>

table items
<table id='list2'>
  <tbody id="documents">
    <tr class="document">
      <td>row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="document">
      <td>row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="document">
      <td>row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="document">
      <td>row 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance.

PS: I am using jquery/bootstrap. Including jquery-ui is also not a problem.

Comment: `<tr>` is invalid child of `<li>` or `<ul>`. What are expected results?

Comment: Expected result is an event that gives me a reference to the dragged element and the target element where it was dropped. So that I could create an ajax call to move the element in the database into the right folder and reload the data in the frontend.

Comment: check out this page which talks about binding events to drag/drops http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop

Comment: Thanks mike510a. Your comment helped me to figure that out. Unfortunately I cannot mark a comment as solution. Or at least I do not see how.